# How can I add an image to my table cell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm following [this tutorial](https://devdactic.com/rest-api-parse-json-swift/) and I'm creating cells for each json entry. Everything works fine without photos:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL")

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
    }

    let user:JSON =  JSON(self.items[indexPath.row])
   // print(user)
    let picURL = "/Users/K/Desktop/aproject/apps/address/addr/Images.xcassets/TabMap.imageset/up_dark.png"//just for tests - some random png
    let url = NSURL(string: picURL)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

    cell!.textLabel?.text = user["description"].string
 //   cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)

    return cell!
}
```

, but when I add photos (uncomment this line):

```
cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

then I'm getting error:

[image]

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

My plan is to pass there an url instead of hardcoded photo (so using `user["photo"]` instead of the link), but for tests I pasted the url to my custom graphic.

How can I add it next to text?

Comment: Note: you should not download your images synchronously, there is no guarantee it will succeed. You should take a look at NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL or downloadTaskWithURL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

Why does the line before have "`cell!`" and the commented out line is "`cell?`".  Also, is this a table view subclass?  Are you sure your imageView outlet is connected?

More importantly, you should do an error check when loading your image data.

That is:

```
if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
{
    cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the local image:

```
cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:"ImageName")
```