# Load image automatic on start Swift tableview

Tags: ios, swift

I have a super small problem... I have done a RSS feed app and on opening I have the list of all the articles but the images are not loading until I will start to scroll on the feed.

The code that I used for download the pics and append them to every cell of the tableview is the following:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                // execute on main thread
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data, scale: 12)
                //cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
```

I insert this code inside:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I found a possible solution but when I'm implementing it the app is becoming a bit slow:

```
if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!){
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data as Data, scale: 12)
        }
```

Comment: Use this library **https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage** super easy to use.

Comment: You could prefetch (and cache) some of the images (in `viewDidLoad` or anywhere that makes sense for your app) and implement a function that would ask for more as the user scrolls the tableView. Keep in mind though that is _not_ as trivial as it seems (if you want a really performant, memory efficient & robust solution), but is something that you will learn a lot from implementing it. A more common solution, especially for lists of arbitrary length, is to set a placeholder, fetch & cache while the user scrolls...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add an image to my table cell in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531441/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-my-table-cell-in-swift)

Comment: Are you calling `URLSession` in `cellForRowAt`? If so, this would cause your app to run very slowly since you're making an API call every time your cell scrolls into view.

Comment: @D.Greg yes, I'm converting a string in URL and then using it ... There is no way for make it faster and without lag?

Comment: You shouldn't make API calls in `cellForRowAt`. You can call it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, make `struct` of the cell models and create an array of the models in the viewController. Then call `tableView.reloadData()` on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library and import it in your class

```
cell.yourImageView!.sd_setImage(with: yourImageURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeHolderImageName") , options: .continueInBackground, completed: nil)
```

It will download and automatically load your images in table cell imageViews.Just give a dummy placeHolder image to place in imageView while your image is downloading.

Answer (score -1):

Please go through the defination of cellForRowAt datasource method. 
This method will call only when it comes on display view. At this time image will download.

I suggest you to use SDWebImage cache library, which will not download image once downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use this line  guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return } as follow.

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }


                DispatchQueue.main.async() {
guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return }
                    // execute on main thread
                    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data, scale: 12)
                    //cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }

            task.resume()

        }

The purpose of the line is to check if the cell is visible on the screen or not. If visible in that case it will plot the image on the cell's image view else guard statement return from the .cellForRow(IndexPath)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I add the new line and I'm receiving this warning and nothing was changed actually : "UITableView.cellForRow(at:) must be used from main thread only"

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `UITableView.cellForRow(at:)` yourself. It's a delegate method called at the right time by the table view. Also, by putting it in the block, you are not running it on the main thread, which is why there is a warning.

Comment: Abizern FYI, i am not calling the delegate's cellForRow(at:). It is table view's cell for row. Please check from Documentation @ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow